# clang __asm__ with labels in case statment, gets error: invalid operand for instruction

Tags: clang, x86-64, inline-assembly, att

I am trying to add `labels` in `C` source code(instrumentation); with a small experience with assembly, comipler is `clang`; I have got a strange behavior with `__asm__` and labels in `CASE` statements !!!;
here is what I have tried:

```
// Compiles successfully.
int main()
{
     volatile unsigned long long a = 3;
      switch(8UL)
      {
         case 1UL:
            //lbl:;
            __asm__ ("movb %%gs:%1,%0": "=q" (a): "m" (a));
            a++;
      }
    return 0;
}
```

and this :

```
// Compiles successfully.
int main()
{
     volatile unsigned long long a = 3;
      switch(8UL)
      {
         case 1UL:
            lbl:;
            //__asm__ ("movb %%gs:%1,%0": "=q" (a): "m" (a));
            a++;
      }
    return 0;
}
```

command:

```
 clang -c examples/a.c
examples/a.c:5:14: warning: no case matching constant switch condition '8'
      switch(8UL)
             ^~~
1 warning generated.
```

BUT this:

```
// not Compile.
int main()
{
     volatile unsigned long long a = 3;
      switch(8UL)
      {
         case 1UL:
            lbl:;
            __asm__ ("movb %%gs:%1,%0": "=q" (a): "m" (a));
            a++;
      }
    return 0;
}
```

the error:

```
             ^~~
examples/a.c:9:22: error: invalid operand for instruction                                                                                                                                     
            __asm__ ("movb %%gs:%1,%0": "=q" (a): "m" (a));
                     ^
<inline asm>:1:21: note: instantiated into assembly here                                                                                                                                      
        movb %gs:-16(%rbp),%rax
                           ^~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

I am using :

```
clang --version
clang version 9.0.0-2 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

IMPORTANT; this will compile successfully with `gcc`.

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I am working on Ubuntu 19 ,64 BIT.
any Help please..

---

**EDIT**

Based on the accepted answer below:

- The `__asm__` statement itself cause error (different sizes).
- The `__asm__`  is unreachable.
- Adding Label to the statement makes it reachable.
- `GCC` ignores it.
- `Clang` does not ignore it.

Comment: Note that `clang` uses its built-in assembler on inline asm statements.  GCC always uses the external `as` from Binutils, just doing text substitution on the `asm()` statement; GAS is different and sometimes less picky than clang's built-in assembler.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Thanks for the clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`movb` is 8-bit operand-size, `%rax` is 64-bit because you used `unsigned long long`.  Just use `mov` to do a load of the same width as the output variable, or use `movzbl %%gs:%1, %k0` to zero-extend to 64-bit.  (Explicitly to 32-bit with `movzbl`, and implicitly to 64-bit by writing the 32-bit low half of the 64-bit register (the `k` modifier in `%k0`))

Surprised GCC doesn't reject that as well; maybe GCC removes it as dead code because of the unreachable `case` in `switch(8)`.  If you look at GCC's asm output, it probably doesn't contain that instruction.